# arithmetic of converge series question

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}a_{n\:}$ converges and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}b_{n\:}$ converges.
 how to proof that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}a_{n\:}-b_n$ also converges?

Comment: What do you know about the corresponding statement for sequences? Note an infinite sum converges if and only if its sequence of partial sums converges.

Comment: it's better to write $\sum_{n}(a_n -b_n)$

Answer (score 1):

Lets call the infinite sum of $a$ the $S_a$, similiarly $S_b$ the sum of $b$

The sum of diferences can be expresed as the diference of two sums
$$S_{a-b}=S_a-S_b$$

saying that a sum $S$ converges is the same as saying that $S<\infty$
so
$S_a<\infty $ and $ S_b<\infty$

now without loss of generality, lets say that $S_a\geq S_b$

thus we can substract $S_a$ from $S_b$ in the inequality and it will still hold:
$$S_b-S_a<\infty$$

Comment: that's if they are allowed to use the fact that you can interchange convergent sums. Usually in such cases students are expected to use the fact that $|s_n - L| \leq \epsilon $ for $ n > N$